# Uncertain response from Combobox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am working in winform and using combobox.

I set the properties of combobox in this sequence

```
combobox.DisplayMember 
combobox.ValueMember 
combobox.DataSource
```

Binding Code is

```
   private void BindBranch()
    {
        BranchClass branch = new BranchClass();
        branch.Active = true;
        branch.Company = Startup.CompID;
        if (branch.GetAll(out dtBranch, out result))
        {
            cmbBranch.DisplayMember = "br_name";
            cmbBranch.ValueMember = "br_id";
            cmbBranch.DataSource = dtBranch;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }
    }
```

I have used combobox in my application several times, I don't know where I am making mistake as

> Sometime SelectedItem property returns exact value (int,string) based
>   on the data type of "ValueMember" property, but sometime it returns
>   "DataRowView", in which case an InvalidCastException is thrown.

I've read this is because of the sequence in which properties are setting in combobox. But this is not the case now.

Binding code is

[image]

Calling code is

```
private void BindEmployee() 
{
    employee.Branch = Convert.ToInt32(cmbBranch.SelectedItem); // InvalidCastException thrown here
    employee.Active = true;

    var dt = new DataTable();
    if (employee.GetEmployee(out dt, out result, false))
    {
        cmbEmployee.DisplayMember = "emp_name";
        cmbEmployee.ValueMember = "emp_id";
        cmbEmployee.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DJKRAZE Its winform, we don't have to bind the data manually after assigning the data source to it.

Comment: you are stating ComboBox.. but what you are selecting looks like a DataGridView.. can you update your title or question to reflect that

Comment: @DJKRAZE It is a combobox, what you are looking at is the data table visualizer, You could look at it in debug watch window

Comment: Ok not a problem..let me edit my answer...

Comment: Can you post the code for the binding method? I'm curious what collection is being bound to the combo box and the sequence in terms of population and binding.

Comment: @frinkenstein789 I've updated the binded code, please review the question now.

Comment: Thanks - now is it possible to post the BranchClass code? I'd really to see what it is that is getting set as the DataSource. I suspect that it's changing in some cases which is why you are getting different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are after the `br_id`. Have you tried:

```
employeeBranch = ConvertToInt32(cmBranch.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Please verify the second screeshot of the question .

Comment: Not sure what you mean? "SelectedValue" will return "ValueMember", SelectedItem will return the base object is the selection is null, maybe this is why your getting the datarow in some cases

Comment: My bad, your answer was right, I was still using "SelectedItem" instead of "SelectedValue". Thanks works like a charm

Comment: Thanks for the response, and it works as per you suggested, but still I want to get cleared why SelectedItem sometimes returns actual value and some times datarowview.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the selected DataRowView from a ComboBox

Since you used data binding to populate the combo box. In that case use the SelectedItem property of combo box. It will probably contain a DataRowView, so you can use code like this.

```
DataRowView viewRow = (DataRowView)cmbBranch.SelectedItem;
DataRow row = viewRow.Row;
```

Comment: No it didn't work. I've updated the question with screen shots. may be it'll help you

Comment: I know this work in this condition, but the thing is about the uncertainty, in half of the cases, it'll give me the error that combobox.selecteditem is int and can't be type casted in datarowview. I want to know, in which scenario it returns datarowview and in which int/string or other datatype based on selecteditem.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround can be to check what type is returned by cmbBranch.SelectedItem as below:

```
object item = cmbBranch.SelectedItem;
int branchId;
if (item is int)
   branchId = item as int;
else if (item is DataRowView)
   branchId = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)item)["BR_ID"].ToString());
```

I am not sure if this is the efficient solution, but can be a workaround!

Comment: This workaround will definitely do the job, but the question still stands, why these different behaviours. I have developed a hugs application based on this workaround, now I wants to move logically rather than hit and trial.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `br_id` use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`.

```
int id = (int)cmBranch.SelectedValue;
```

`SelectedValue` returns the value of the property specified by `ValueMember`. `SelectedItem` should always return the data row.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and it works as per you suggested, but still I want to get cleared why SelectedItem sometimes returns actual value and some times datarowview.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you actually assign the `SelectedItem` to an `int`?

Comment: Please look at the Calling Code section in my question.

Comment: Does `Convert.ToInt32(cmbBranch.SelectedItem)` really sometimes yield an `int` other than `0`?